# Counting multiple columns from multiple tables with a JOIN in SQL Server within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the task of creating a stored procedure that will count `SalesOrderID` and `SalesOrderDetailID` columns from three different tables by `orderdate`.

Table 1: `Salesorderheader`

Columns

- Sales OrderID
- Orderdate

Table 2: `Salesorderdetail`

Columns

- Sales OrderID
- Sales OrderDetailID

I am inner joining both tables on the `SalesID` column, but I keep getting the same count for both the `Salesid` and the `salesdetailId` column.

When count both columns separately, I get the correct count, but when I put it in a join I get the same count for both columns.

My question is why is SQL Server making the columns equal?

Comment: You should edit your question and show the query.

Answer (score 2):

When you do a count of multiple columns in a single query, it is simply counting the total number of records.  What you need to do is use sub-queries to get counts for different columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a count of `salesid` and `salesdetailid`:

```
select count(distinct salesid), count(salesdetailid)
from Salesorderheader soh join
     Salesorderdetail sod
     on soh.salesid = sod.salesid;
```

In general `count(<column name>)` counts the non-null values of the column.  It does not count the number of distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

The `Count` function counts the total number of `Non Null` rows including the duplicates. In your case salesOrderID would have duplicate values in the result set after the join with SalesOrderDetail table. Either you would have to use

```
Count(Distinct SalesOrderID)
```

OR you can use a subquery like

```
select (select COUNT(SalesorderID) from Salesorderheader) as OrderIDCount,
(select COUNT(SalesorderDetailID) from SalesOrderDetail) as OrderDetailIDCount
```